# WPF LabelFormat property

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I have a chart, where I display big values such as millions and billions.
So instead of displaying `1000000` I want show it in more readable format such as `1 mil` or `1 bil`

```
<telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
    <telerik:LinearAxis LabelFormat="" Foreground="#FF0094F7" Title="Revenue"/>
</telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
```

I know that it is possible achieve setting `LabelFormat` property but I am not sure how it works. Can someone give me an example? Thanks!